# JPA query equivalent to mysql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

Below is mysql query which is working fine and giving me expected results on mysql console.

```
select * from omni_main as t where t.date_time BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2011', '08', '01'),'%Y%m%d') AND LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2012', '08','01'), '%Y%m%d')) group by year(date_time),month(date_time)
```

I need its JPA equivalent query. Below is what I am trying but its returning nothing.

```
String queryStr = "select * from OmniMainEntity o where o.dateTime BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('"+fromYear+"', '"+fromMonth+"','01'), '%Y%m%d') AND " 
               +"LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('"+toYear+"', '"+toMonth+"','01'), '%Y%m%d'))";

Query query = manager.createQuery(queryStr);
System.out.println("Result Size: "+query.getResultList().size());
```

Here `fromYear`, `fromMonth`, `toYear`, `toMonth` are method parameters using in creating `queryStr`.

Please suggest where I may wrong!

Any other way to achieve goal is also welcome!

Comment: in JPA until you use createQuery and not nativeQuery , your code will work in all databases

Comment: @chrylis I did changes what you told but still result size zero is returning!

Comment: correct me if i am wrong : for JPA we do SELECT obj FROM ANYTHING obj .... you still have select *

Answer (score 1):

As you are using JPA Query, it would be better to not use database-specified sql function, such as STR_TO_DATE.

You can have a try by this way.(A Hibernate way, JPA should be similiar):

First, you can parse a java.util.Date object from "fromYear" and "fromMonth" like below:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date startDate = df.parse(fromYear + "" + fromMonth + "01");
Date endDate = df.parse(.....);
```

Then, set them into the JPA query.

```
String queryStr = "select * from OmniMainEntity o where o.dateTime BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate)"; // The query now changed to database independent
Query query = manager.createQuery(queryStr);
query.setDate("startDate", startDate);
query.setDate("endDate", endDate);
```

At last, doing the search:

```
System.out.println("Result Size: "+query.getResultList().size());
```

Comment: dateTime value in db is like '2011-08-29 01:19:33' and for searching we have year and month. So, your suggested way will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't have a verb in it. You probably want `SELECT` in there:

```
SELECT o FROM OmniMainEntity o WHERE...
```

Also, you should be using parameterized and typed queries, and it's usual to use short names (`o` instead of `omniMainEnt`) to make your queries readable.